# UI freezes even process start with separate thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, data-binding

In My application have time consuming process.There fore i try to do that operation in separate thread.Even i Stared it separate thread my Main UI still freezes during the time of long running process.But still i couldn't  figure out the reason for that?Some thing wrong in my code?

My Event Hander Code

```
private void BtnloadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (null != cmbSource.SelectedItem)
   {
     string selectedITem = ((FeedSource) cmbSource.SelectedItem).Url;
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedITem))
     {                    
        Thread starter = new Thread(() => BindDataUI(selectedITem));
        starter.IsBackground = true;
        starter.Start();
     }            
}

private void BindDataUI(string url)
{
   if (feedGridView1.InvokeRequired)
   {
      BeginInvoke(new Action(() => BindDataGrid(url)));
   }
   else
     BindDataGrid(ss);
}


 private void BindDataGrid(string selectedItem)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      //Time consuming Process
    }
 }
```

Comment: You'll need to split BindDataGrid into UI-related and not-UI-related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thread is completely useless :-)

In your thread you are executing `BindDataUI` which marshals the execution back to the UI thread using `Invoke`.

Your complete code is equivalent to this:

```
private void BtnloadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (null != cmbSource.SelectedItem)
   {
     string selectedITem = ((FeedSource) cmbSource.SelectedItem).Url;
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedITem))
     {     
        BindDataGrid(selectedITem);
     }            
}

private void BindDataGrid(string selectedItem)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      //Time consuming Process
    }
}
```

It would be better to only marshal these parts of `BindDataGrid` to the UI thread that really need to run on this thread because they need to update the UI.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.It bit difficult to me understand what you are saying.can u explain me bit more

Comment: The call to `BeginInvoke` executes the specified code on the UI thread. So, you are starting a background thread without really using it, because all it does is to marshal the code back to the UI thread...